# Handling DOM events in JavaScript classes

Tags: javascript, scope, dom-events, prototype

(Feel free to reword the title; I find this hard to put into words.)

I've created a JavaScript "class" (for lack of a better word; I know JS isn't class-based) that represents a `textarea` and a `div`.
Every time the textarea's value is changed, I want the div's content to update accordingly, so I thought to assign an `onkeyup` event handler to the textarea — however, that turned out to be more problematic than I thought.

Here's the relevant part of my HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="MyTextarea.js"></script>
<script>
    var ta = new MyTextarea('container');
</script>
```

And here's the JS I've written so far:

```
function MyTextarea(id) {

    this.textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    this.box = document.createElement('div');

    var container = document.getElementById(id);
    container.appendChild(this.textarea);
    container.appendChild(this.box);

    this.textarea.onkeyup = this._synchronize;

}


MyTextarea.prototype._synchronize = function () {

    this.box.innerHTML = this.textarea.value;

};
```

Instead of working, this insists on throwing a "this.textarea" is undefined" error. It turns out that — much to my surprise — in the `_synchronize` function, `this` doesn't refer to the MyTextarea object, but instead to the textarea element itself. I'm puzzled as to why that would be.

What am I doing wring and/or not getting here? Is it because I'm doing this within a "class"? How can I achieve this instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing context when you assign event handler as direct function reference. So in other words, instead of `MyTextarea` instance object `this` points to `HTMLTextAreaElement` object.

There are multiple solutions, for example you can bind context explicitly:

```
this.textarea.onkeyup = this._synchronize.bind(this);
```

Or you could do it old-school way:

```
var self = this;
this.textarea.onkeyup = function() {
    self._synchronize();
};
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd almost forgotten about `bind` and never really knew what it was for - guess this is the first time where it makes sense for me to use it.